# How to prove greedy algorithm optimality

Tags: algorithm, intervals, discrete-mathematics

> Let `S` be a set of intervals (containing n number of intervals) of the natural numbers that might overlap and N be a list of numbers (containing n number of numbers).

I want to find the smallest subset (let's call P) of S such that for each number
in our list N, there exists at least one interval in P that contains it. The intervals in P are allowed to overlap.

Trivial example:

```
S = {[1..4], [2..7], [3..5], [8..15], [9..13]}
N = [1, 4, 5]
// so P = {[1..4], [2..7]}
```

---

I found a solution to this problem shown below

```
N = MergeSort (N)
upper, lower = infinity, -1
P = empty set
for each q in N do
     if (q>=lower and q<=upper)=False
          max_interval = [-infinity, infinity]
          for each r in S do
              if q in r then
                 if r.rightEndPoint > max_interval.rightEndPoint
                     max_interval = r
          P.append(max_interval)
          lower = max_interval.leftEndPoint
          upper = max_interval.rightEndPoint
          S.remove(max_interval)
```

I have found this solution, but I am not entirely sure how to prove the optimality of a greedy algorithm (that is prove, that is will always give the best result).

My question: How can I prove the optimality of this greedy solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com). Also, this looks dangerously similar to the set cover problem - so, are you sure your algorithm is optimal?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science/math, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your algorithm reaches optimal solution. I am not good with formal proofs but hopefully the following arguments should be convincing.

1. The array N is sorted in ascending order and you are accessing elements accordingly in non-decreasing order. In other words, the current element is always >= previous element.
2. For each element, we first check whether it can be accommodated in the previously chosen interval and if not, only then we proceed to step 3, otherwise we skip to the next element.
3. For the current element, we are choosing the (so far un-chosen) interval in S such that its 'end' point is as large as possible. This makes sense because that way we can accommodate most number of elements that follow our current element. For example, if the current element is 10, and we have two candidate intervals [8, 12] and [9, 15], under no circumstances shall we choose the former because we know that all the following elements have to be greater than 10.